# React Browser navigation not going to sub urls

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating a web app using expo web and react native. My base file App.js file is defined as follows. It works well in localhost however on live uploaded, It works only on root path e.g `https://ip-address.com/`
If I try to open any other page

```
https://ip-address.com/share/?abc
https://ip-address.com/menu
```

It fails giving

> This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the
> current directory or 404.html in the root directory.

```
const MenuStack = createStackNavigator({
    menu    : MenuScreen, 
    share   : ShareScreen,
    details: {
        screen: DetailsScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false
        }
    },
    success  : SuccessScreen, 
    scheduled: ScheduledScreen, 
    review   : ReviewScreen, 
    checkout : CheckoutScreen,
    story    : StoryScreen,
    confirm  : ConfirmScreen,
    order    : OrderScreen,
    receipt: ReceiptScreen, 
    area: AreaScreen,
    payment: PaymentScreen
});
MenuStack.navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
}

const SearchStack = createStackNavigator({
    search : SearchScreen,
    details: {
        screen: DetailsScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false
        },
      }
    }
);
SearchStack.navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
}

const BranchesStack = createStackNavigator({
    branches: BranchesScreen, 
    branchDetails: {
        screen: BranchDetailsScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerShown: false
        },
      }
    }
);
BranchesStack.navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
}

const StatusStack = createStackNavigator({
    status: StatusScreen,
    receipt: ReceiptScreen, 
});
StatusStack.navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
}

const SuccessStack = createStackNavigator({
    success: SuccessScreen  
});
SuccessStack.navigationOptions = {
    headerShown: false
}

/*
const createApp = Platform.select({
    web: config => createBrowserApp(config),
    default: config => createAppContainer(config),
});*/

const MainContainer = createBrowserApp(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {       
            splash  : SplashScreen,     
            menu    : MenuStack,
            search  : SearchStack,
            branches: BranchesStack,
            status  : StatusStack,
            success : SuccessScreen,
            failure : FailureScreen,
            delivery: DeliveryScreen,
            share   : ShareScreen
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: ""
        }
    )   
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  
    state = {
        showLoading: true,
    }

    globalData = {
        receiptData: undefined,
        color: 'blue'
    }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.saveData(undefined)
    }

    saveData = async data => {

        if(store.defaultLanguage == 'ar')
        {
            RNI18nManager.forceRTL(true);
            // RN won't set the layout direction if we
            // don't restart the app's JavaScript.
            //Updates.reloadFromCache();
        }

        i18n.translations = translations;
          // Set the locale once at the beginning of your app.
        i18n.locale = store.defaultLanguage;
    };
    
    render() {
    
        return (
            <AppProvider>
            <MainContainer />
            </AppProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it an app problem? What happens if you open the mobile browser and navigate directly to `https://ip-address.com/share/?abc`?

Comment: @gbalduzzi it works when i use localhost. in case of firebase upload it doesn't work. Gives error 4o4 not found

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening `https://ip-address.com/share/?abc` it's triyng to find `share` directory and index.html inside it. You are currently hosting your js bundle under `https://ip-address.com` and you should host it for every path that might be part of the url (`https://ip-address.com/**`).

For firebase you need to add sth like this

```
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
```

If you have assets there you will need to modify source field not to match them.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

Answer (score 0):

It's an normal issue with Single page applications, as the routes are handled by JS not by the server so when server try to manage the route it throws not found.
Solution is to tell the server to redirect to index.html for every route it hits, rest of the things are handled by JS.

In your case, If you are using firebase CLI for deploying your application. You can do following to get this issue resolved:

If account is not already setup do

```
firebase login
```

and follow the next steps in the console

once done hit

```
firebase init
```

Choose `hosting` by pressing space in the terminal specify the public directory for the files on server now firebase asks if your application is single page application or not, press Y

Hit

```
firebase deploy
```

The issue would be fixed.